# mysql query for excluding fields

Tags: mysql, sql

A poll result table:

ID, NAME, ANSWER char(1)

query which select Name start with 'N' but answer not have 'Y'

My try

```
select * 
from poll 
where name like "N%" AND answer NOT LIKE "Y"
```

It is not working

Comment: Yes it is - prove me wrong...

Comment: As always, never write "It is not working". Explain why you came to this conclusion. Error messages? Ran in which environment? Etc.

Comment: Without going into the well justified previous comments: you either use `...NOT LIKE '%Y%'` or `<> 'Y'`. Second, you are using `"` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You had missing `;` after the query. should be used `;`

```
select * 
from poll 
where name like 'N%' AND answer NOT LIKE 'Y';
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why this query which looks substantively the same as the one in the question might 'work'?

Comment: @raju are you help my answer for you?